# How to replace fetched values with another column while querying with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, replace, sql-server-2008-r2, multiple-columns

Alright let me explain my question with example

We have 1 table
This table contains

```
Id
Name
Number
```

Now example

```
1 House 4
2 Hospital 3
3 Airport 1
4 Station 2
```

Now when fetching as `select * from table`

I want to replace third column number values with that number representing Name

So example of fetching

```
1 House Station
2 Hospital Airport
3 Airport House
4 Station Hospital
```

How can i do this ? thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select t1.id, 
       t1.name,
       t2.name as name2
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2 on t1.number = t2.id
```

You can join the same table twice to replace the `number` with the `name`. The `on` contidion in the join matches the table again and then you can select the `name` from that table (`t2`)

### [SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa7df/2)

Comment: could not make it work. there are not 2 different tables. it is on same table.

Comment: replace `your_table` with your table name but net the alias names be.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an explicit join:

```
select t.id, t.name, t2.name as otherName
from t left outer join
     t t2
     on t2.number = t.id
```

Comment: @Monster FYI this is exactly the same query as `juergen`'s, except "T" is used as the table name instead of "your_table". Both incredibly have the same issue, you shouldn't name both columns "name", which will make the 2nd hidden from some front-end IDEs, or SQLFiddle

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi . . . Good point Richard.  These will work in SQL Server Management Studio, but the duplicate name could be a problem in other situations.  By the way, Juergen posted his answer 16 seconds before I did, so if one is accepted, it should be his.

Comment: the following part of the question can you check ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771906/how-to-replace-a-column-values-when-querying-with-left-join-command-mssql-2008-r