# How to replace a column values when querying with left join command SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: t-sql, replace, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

Alright let me explain my question with example

We have a table that contains

```
Id
Name
Number
```

Now example

```
1 House 4
2 Hospital 3
3 Airport 'null'
4 Station 2
```

---

```
 select t1.id, 
       t1.name,
       t2.name as name2
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2 on t1.number = t2.id
```

Ok when querying as the above, that 'null' value containing column is giving error. So i want to modify above query in a way that it will return name2 as null and won't give error for that rows.

So the result I expect should be:

```
1 House Station
2 Hospital Airport
3 Airport null
4 Station Hospital
```

This null here is as string.

The current error I get

> *Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'null' to data type smallint.*

thank you

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as `varchar` and `null` as strings containing the word `null`?

Comment: Well because of bad design but can't change things right now. Need some help :D

Comment: Fixing the design now seems the best thing to do to me but anyway is `null` the only non numeric value in that column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix your database design. Meantime, use [NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) to get your expected results:

```
select t1.id, 
       t1.name,
       t2.name as name2
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2 on NULLIF( t1.number, 'NULL' ) = t2.id
```

Comment: @MartinSmith. ups! Thanks. Right now for you?